# I am trying to add the foreground image here and I am facing an error here

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am just trying to learn about the app icon so I tried to add the foreground and background xml files here but the foreground file linking doesn't work here for some reason here is the error message

> ERROR: C:\Users\syed\AndroidStudioProjects\TipTime\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher.xml:4: AAPT: error: resource drawable/ic_launcher_foreground (aka com.example.tiptime:drawable/ic_launcher_foreground) not found.

I tried to delete it and add it again but it is still showing this error here..

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your related error code. If I have your code related to this error, I could provide a more accurate answer.

First, after you delete the image file in the mipmap folder, you can recreate the icon image.
(New -> Create as Image Asset)

Or, you can go into the file and formatted the contents (aka made a change), and that fixed the build system recognising the file.

Good Luck.